# Calling linux server page from classic asp page

Tags: apache, asp-classic

There is a new requirment where from classic asp page i have to interact with linux server and fire a page in that server. never worked for cross-platform, how can i do it?

Comment: Can you show us your code first, please - i.e. what you've got so far?

Comment: Thanks Paul for your reply but m not authorized to show. Iam noob for this topic and just need a basic guide or headstart to start the development.

Comment: So you can't show us the line you have that contains the link?...